# openpyxl - unusual output is shown in the cell?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am testing out openpyxl for my usecase. A2 cell is showing **###** instead **43**. What could be the reason ?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()

ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = 42
ws['A2'] = datetime.datetime.now()
ws['A2'] = "=SUM(A1, 1)"
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

I am guesssing, openpyxl is not able to change underlying type of the cell ie from datetime to formula.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `openpyxl` but with **Excel** itself.

Comment: You could convert your `datetime` object to string using [strftime method](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime) to make it work.

Comment: You can check the data type of the cell in openpyxl and even set it manually.

Comment: @CharlieClark dint know you can set datatype of cell through openpyxl, intresting. I will explore this. Thanks!!

Comment: @SyedShahzer yes should'nt openpyxl throw error if i am inserting value having incompatible datatype ?

Comment: @MayankPant it isn't incompatible. It would have this date `1900-02-12 0:00:00`. You can see it when you expand the column. Also the cell gets the custom format `yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss` automatically in excel.